# Open a pdf file stored in firebase storage in my app using react native expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, pdf, expo, firebase-storage

I want to open a pdf file that are in my firebase storage. Firebase storage gives me a url and when i used that url in my webview it start downloading. I don't want to download that pdf  file. I just want to open that pdf file in my App. 
Please help me
I will be very Thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the PDF using expo FileSystem

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/

Once the file is downloaded, you can use "rn-pdf-reader-js"

https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js

Comment: Thank You soo much sir

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that can be used even in an expo app.

1. Install `npm i react-native-openanything`
2. Import it into your code as, `import * as OpenAnything from 'react-native-openanything'`
3. Assume that the uri for the pdf to be read is stored in a usestate as `pdfUri`
4. Create a button component
   `<Button`
   `title="Open PDF"`
   `onPress={() => OpenAnything.Pdf(pdfUri)}`
   `/>`

That's it now you can open the pdf without getting it downloaded :)